# How to select value in one column based on another value in the same column, to then use in an equation?

Tags: r, csv, multiple-columns, analysis, equation

Example data set in the picture

[image]

If percentage is 35 with their corresponding response values (average of the response values = A), I want to select another set of percentages that equal 100-35 = 65 and those corresponding responses (average of the response values = B). These percentages and responses are in the same columns.

I want to multiple A by 65% and B by 35%, before adding the two together.

I would want to do that for an entire data set so that I can get a "flipped" percentage and response accuracy.

Comment: In what language (eg MySQL)?

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code can help you

```
with(
  aggregate(response ~ ., df, mean),
  sum(
    rowMeans(
      cbind(
        response * (1 - percentage / 100),
        response[match(100 - percentage, percentage)] * percentage / 100
      )
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[1] 2.175
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(percentage = c(35, 35, 40, 40, 45, 45, 50, 50, 
55, 55, 60, 60, 65, 65), response = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
))
```